# Winsorizing variables at 1st and 99th percentile

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a data frame containing continuous and discrete variables and the continuous variables need to be winsorized at the 1st and 99th percentile. I use the `DescTools::Winsorize` function however when I try to run my code I get an error `unused argument (.SDcols = winz_var)`.
For context, `winz_var` is a vector containing the variable names I need to winsorize.

This is the exact line I am trying to run. 
`model_df2 <- model_df2 %>% .[,(winz_var) := lapply(.SD, Winsorize, probs = c(0.01, 0.99), na.rm = TRUE, type = 1), .SDcols = winz_var]`

This is what my data frame looks like

[image]

Comment: You should post the full code, or at least a few lines before for context. The fact that this line throws the error doesn't mean that this specific line is the source of your issues.

Comment: Have you tried without the pipe? `model_df2[,(winz_var) := lapply(.SD, Winsorize, probs = c(0.01, 0.99), na.rm = TRUE, type = 1), .SDcols = winz_var]`. Have you checked `all(winz_var %in% names(model_df2))`? Are you using a `data.table` version > 1.8.3 so that vectors on the LHS of `:=` is supported?